# Cut string in bash based on position of occurrence in first line

Tags: bash, macos, awk, sed

I'm trying to select specific columns (2 and 3) from command output, where the column separator is also present in the text. Consider this example text (fictional part of `nmcli` output):

```
           SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL
      Something 12:34:56:78:98:ab -10  1
Something guest a2:34:56:78:98:ab -10  2
        Network b2:34:56:78:98:ab -20  3 
 Public network c2:34:56:78:98:ab -30  4
```

Columns are split by single spaces, but there are also single spaces in the SSIDs. Without those, it's an easy solution using `cut`.

In GNU `sed`, I somehow made it work using `\w\s\w`  to replace spaces in SSIDs with underscores:

```
sed -e 's/\w\s\w/_/g'
```

But that doesn't work on the Mac. So my second best idea is splitting by position. Is it possible to:

1. determine the position of BSSID, RSSI and CHANNEL strings in first line
2. cut between BSSID_pos and RSSI_pos (1) and RSSI_pos - CHANNEL (2)

Is it there a smarter way? Those spaces in SSIDs also confuse awk, so

```
awk '{print $2 " " $3}'
```

doesn't work in those lines.

--- EDIT ---
The problem is, there are also spaces in the last field when using on data produced by MacOS airport -s, so I can't go from back either:

```
                            SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
                             AA1 d8:12:b6:b8:10:d5 -92  9       Y -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) RSN(PSK/AES/AES)
                     XXXXX Guest ba:11:e4:4a:01:71 -90  6       Y -- RSN(PSK/AES/AES)
                         Netwrrk 5a:99:68:b7:0d:ca -89  36      Y DE RSN(PSK/AES/AES)
                      T-3_7edb87 64:11:ea:7e:db:87 -87  11      Y -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) RSN(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
                           abcde 58:22:8f:c6:7c:de -86  6       Y -- RSN(PSK/AES/AES)
                           abcde 64:66:88:3f:b2:9a -78  8       Y -- RSN(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
                           ababa 74:ac:77:b1:e3:59 -74  6       Y -- RSN(PSK/AES/AES)
```

Apologies for two questions in one; thank you all!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output for the 2 sample input blocks you posted. Also, in that last sample input block you posted - do your "CC" values in lines 2 and later REALLY not start at the same character position as the line 1 header and instead start 1 char earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using GNU `grep` here(tested in RedHat), which will simply catch the needed string by using regex in it. Written and tested with shown samples Only.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/KecBTt/1) for used regex.

```bash
grep -oP '(?<=\s)[0-9a-f]{2}(:[0-9a-f]{2}){5}\s+-?[[:digit:]]{2}'  Input_file
```

***OR*** in `perl` try following (thanks to @tripleee for this):

```perl
perl -nle 'm/(?<=\s)[0-9a-f]{2}(:[0-9a-f]{2}){5}\s+-?[[:digit:]]{2}/ and print "$&"'  Input_file
```

Comment: This will break if the SSID happens to contain a colon. You can probably tighten it up some; the MAC always contains exactly six octets.

Comment: @tripleee, ok so you mean I should mention alnum's 6 occurrences only?

Comment: Yeah, something like `grep -oP '(?<=\s)[0-9a-f]{2}(?:[0-9a-f}(2}){5}\s+[[:alnum:]]+'` to also get the field after the MAC.

Comment: @tripleee, You mean `grep -oP '(?<=\s)[0-9a-f]{2}(:[[:alnum:]]{2}){5}\s+-?[[:digit:]]{2}' Input_file` like this, looks like there was typo in your previous comment, cheers.

Comment: The MAC contains only hex characters separated by colons, but yeah, that should of course be `[0-9a-f]` not `[0-9a-f}`

Comment: Apple grep doesn't understand perl (-P option) regex... I'll try to convert it and see if I can make it work :)

Comment: @May11, Sorry I don't have MAC with me. If possible you can install GNU `grep` and then this can do wonders for you :)

Comment: You can approximate it with `perl -nle 'm/(?<=\s)[0-9a-f]{2}(:[0-9a-f]{2}){5}\s+-?[[:digit:]]{2}/ and print "$&"'`

Comment: Whoa, that works - and perl is even installed by default on Mac! Thanks!

Comment: @May11, your welcome, thanks to tripleee also for using previously used regex into perl, that's how we learn from one another cheers 

Answer (score 5):

The following has been tested with GNU `awk` and the BSD `awk` that comes with macOS (but as `Ed` commented it should work with any POSIX `awk`):

```bash
$ awk 'NR==1 {n = match($0, /[[:space:]]BSSID[[:space:]]/) + 1}
       NR>1  {$0 = substr($0, n); print $1, $2}' file.txt
12:34:56:78:98:ab -10
a2:34:56:78:98:ab -10
b2:34:56:78:98:ab -20
c2:34:56:78:98:ab -30
```

The first block applies only on the first line and stores the index of `BSSID` in variable `n`. The second block applies to all other lines. It modifies them by suppressing the `n-1` first characters, and prints the new first and second fields.

Just for fun (because it is a bit more complex), here is also a `sed` solution based on the same idea of parsing the header line, and tested with GNU `sed` and the BSD `sed` that comes with macOS.

```bash
$ sed -En '
1 {
  s/^(.*[[:space:]])BSSID[[:space:]].*/\1/
  h
}
2,$ {
  G
  :a
  s/.(.*\n.*)./\1/
  ta
  s/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+).*/\1/
  p
}' file.txt
12:34:56:78:98:ab -10
a2:34:56:78:98:ab -10
b2:34:56:78:98:ab -20
c2:34:56:78:98:ab -30
```

We use extended regular expressions (`-E`) and suppress the default echoing (`-n`).

We first delete the end of the first line starting at `BSSID` (substitute command `s/^(.*[[:space:]])BSSID[[:space:]].*/\1/`) and store the result in the hold space (`h`). With your first example the hold space now contains (beginning and end marked with `^` and `$`):

```
^           SSID $
```

All lines except the first (`2,$`) are modified as follows, and printed (final `p`):

- Append a newline followed by the hold space (`G`). The second line of your example becomes:

  ```
  ^      Something 12:34:56:78:98:ab -10  1\n           SSID $
  ```
- Iterate (loop `:a` ... `ta`) by deleting the first character and the last character after the newline until all characters after the newline have been deleted (substitute command `s/.(.*\n.*)./\1/`). The second line of your example becomes:

  ```
  ^12:34:56:78:98:ab -10  1\n$
  ```
- Delete everything after (and including) the second string of spaces (`s/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+).*/\1/`). The second line of your example becomes:

  ```
  ^12:34:56:78:98:ab -10$
  ```

The GNU `sed` version is a bit more compact, if it matters:

```bash
$ sed -En '1{s/^(.*)\<BSSID\>.*/\1/;h;n}
    {G;:a;s/.(.*\n.*)./\1/;ta;s/^(\S+\s+\S+).*/\1/;p}' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, sometimes there are also spaces at the end when using airport command on Mac in the "security" column so I can't go from back, either :-(

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a representative example such that your question and its answers can be useful also for others.

Comment: That'll work using any POSIX awk.

Answer (score 5):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{ match($0,/BSSID.*RSSI/); next } { $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $1=$1; print }' file
d8:12:b6:b8:10:d5 -92
ba:11:e4:4a:01:71 -90
5a:99:68:b7:0d:ca -89
64:11:ea:7e:db:87 -87
58:22:8f:c6:7c:de -86
64:66:88:3f:b2:9a -78
74:ac:77:b1:e3:59 -74
```

Answer (score 3):

This is why many Unix tools prefer to put the variable-length fields last (compare `ls -l`) but as long as the tail has predictable formatting, just pick out the things counting from the end.

```
sed '2,$s/^.* \([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f] *[-0-9]*\) [0-9]*$/\1/'
```

or

```
awk 'FNR>1{ print $(NF-2) " " $(NF-1) }'
```

A better solution altogether is to read the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmcli) and search for an option to print only the information you need.

```
nmcli -t -f BSSID,RSSI
```

(I can't run `nmcli` inside Docker, it seems, so no way to test this; but I trust you can take it from here even if the command line doesn't directly work.)

Comment: That works on Linux, but not on Mac (you can't specify columns in airport) :-/ Additionally, airport also displays "security" in last column - it can also  sometimes contain spaces, so I also can't do it from the end :-( https://www.macworld.com/article/192323/airportterm.html

Comment: Your question doesn't mention Airport at all; how are we supposed to know? The command seems to have an `-x` option to specify XML output, which lets you similarly pick out the values you want ... but really, (accept one of the answers to the question you actually _asked_ and) ask a new question with more details about your precise requirements.

Comment: Sory you're right about both. I'll use xml and parse it!

Comment: Don't take `OFS`s one and only job away :-). `print $(NF-2), $(NF-1)`

Answer (score 3):

I would harness [`substr` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) of GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
           SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL
      Something 12:34:56:78:98:ab -10  1
Something guest a2:34:56:78:98:ab -10  2
        Network b2:34:56:78:98:ab -20  3 
 Public network c2:34:56:78:98:ab -30  4
```

then

```
awk '{print substr($0,17,22)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
BSSID             RSSI
12:34:56:78:98:ab -10 
a2:34:56:78:98:ab -10 
b2:34:56:78:98:ab -20 
c2:34:56:78:98:ab -30
```

Explanation: I `print` substring starting at 17th character, which is 22 characters long.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*